# pymedtermino sqlite database not found

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to use the module pymedtermino but keep getting teh below error

```
from pymedtermino.snomedct import *
```

> File
>   "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymedtermino__init__.py",
>   line 790, in connect_sqlite3
>       raise IOError('Database %s not available. Please build, or set pymedtermino.DATA_DIR correctly' % path)
>
> OSError: Database
>   C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymedtermino\snomedct.sqlite3
>   not available. Please build, or set pymedtermino.DATA_DIR correctly

i have successfully installed the module

> Collecting PyMedTermino   Downloading PyMedTermino-0.3.3.tar.gz
>   (34.0MB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 34.0MB 25kB/s Building wheels for collected packages: PyMedTermino   Running setup.py
>   bdist_wheel for PyMedTermino ... done   Stored in directory:
>   C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\71\01\91\f3ec03bdc7c10c11093b77f8a5ecef4f855327c1b29107d4dd
>   Successfully built PyMedTermino Installing collected packages:
>   PyMedTermino Successfully installed PyMedTermino-0.3.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After installing PyMedTermino if you try the following code there will be no error:

```
from pymedtermino import *
```

It is clearly mentioned in the documentation that "For SNOMED CT and ICD10, the data are not included (because they are not freely redistributable) but they can be downloaded for free in XML format, for research / academic purpose"

In order to use SNOMED or ICD you have to download SNOMED CT data. Please see the following link for download and installation procedure.

https://pythonhosted.org/PyMedTermino/tuto_en.html

https://pythonhosted.org/PyMedTermino/tuto_en.html#installation

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the global parameter using 
`pymedtermino.DATA_DIR = <path to the SQLite3 files>`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with `setup.py` script in pymedtermino resolving them solves the problem.

1. To set the directory path of data directories one has to directly hard code in setup.py. Using `export DATA_DIR="<path>"` doesn't help.
2. In ICD10_DIR the code by default looks for a file with the name 'icd102010en.xml' which has got changed to  'icd102016en.xml' in the recent version